# Disable "Cannot serve directory" errors

Tags: apache2, apache2.4, directory-listing

On my website I have an `/upload` dir. And I **don't** want people to see a list of the content in the dir (the files in it can still be viewed) - so to me the following error message is not an error.

Is there a way to disable the following error message, while keeping `/upload` Directory Listing disabled/forbidden?

```
[autoindex:error] [pid 17883] [client IP:16603] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/my-site.com/upload/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I don't want it to be in my error.log since I don't consider it an error.

I guess I could make my own "Forbidden" `index.html` file in the dir, but this problem is for multiple folders, so I rather not (if possible).

Comment: it took me so long to use the correct keywords in Google to get to this question where someone also wanted to just mute the error, and not where the solution is just adding `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.jsp index.something`, so thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the affected directories with e.g. RewriteRule and match against the trailing slash and return [F] or [G], which would be silent.  Otherwise, it is not possible to suppress the message directly in mod_autoindex or indirectly at some logging layer.

Comment: Edit: `RewriteRule ^upload/$ - [F]`

Answer (score 1):

```
LogLevel autoindex:crit
```

I solved this by moving up the log level for autoindex module.

Comment: Where should I change this please ?

Comment: @ChamindaBandara, you can add LogLevel inside `<VirtualHost ...> .... </VirtualHost>`, for example ; see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel : `Context: server config, virtual host, directory`