# Apache web server slowed down, followed by PHP Fatal Errors with "referrer: binance.com"

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I noticed that my Ubuntu 16.04 web server slowed down for about 10 minutes recently. I checked my Apache error logs and found the following:

```
[Fri Dec 03 05:03:41.432248 2021] [php7:error] [pid 7002] [client ip:port] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_the_block_template_html() in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/template-canvas.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/template-canvas.php on line 12, referer: binance.com
[Fri Dec 03 05:07:09.326576 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 7081] [client ip:port] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 9, referer: binance.com
[Fri Dec 03 05:07:09.326608 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 7081] [client ip:port] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant WPINC - assumed 'WPINC' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 9, referer: binance.com
[Fri Dec 03 05:07:09.326686 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 7081] [client ip:port] PHP Warning:  require(ABSPATHWPINC/blocks/archives.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 9, referer: binance.com
[Fri Dec 03 05:07:09.326696 2021] [php7:error] [pid 7081] [client ip:port] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'ABSPATHWPINC/blocks/archives.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 9, referer: binance.com
[Fri Dec 03 05:09:11.541500 2021] [php7:error] [pid 7108] [client ip:port] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-block.php:17\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-block.php on line 17, referer: binance.com
```

I tried to discern the meaning of this and found the following: [Getting lots of server errors directory index forbidden by Options directive from same referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831725/getting-lots-of-server-errors-directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive-fro) and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-of-undefined-constant-abspath/

Does this log mean that bots originating from binance.com are attempting to access/use Wordpress functions on my website? Is this a cause for concern, and is it likely or possible to have caused response times to slow down for a short period? If it is a cause for concern, is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening? I would have thought that for the server to slow down, there would have to be lots of requests occurring, and thus many more errors logged than what I found.

Comment: Those are errors in the code and it can be occur even if you access it via URL, no need to be bot. For example _wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 9_ should not have `ABSPATHWPINC/blocks/archives.php` but `ABSPATH . WPINC . '/blocks/archives.php';`. And more class, function, constant should be exists in WordPress but not in yours. So, it is possible that your WordPress core files has been rewritten by something.

Comment: From each line of errors, open your file and locate to the line that error tells you and compare with [WordPress original files on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress). Maybe re-upload WordPress core files from the original one.

Comment: @vee thank you for this. I have checked the three files and my WP files match what is in the Github. The one you mentioned matches with ```require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/blocks/archives.php';```, template-canvas.php has ```$template_html = get_the_block_template_html();``` and class-wp-widget-block.php has ```class WP_Widget_Block extends WP_Widget {```

I am using the latest version of WP. Is there any way to trace what could be overwriting this?

Comment: If your WordPress core files has been overwritten, it is possible that come from plugins or themes. This is often found that it come from bad plugins or themes such as null (illegal) script. There are many security plugins to scan and prevent this but I'm not sure which one is the best, I'm using Sucuri and it seems to be good.